# OpenVPN won't start on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, linuxmint

I was trying to setup an OpenVPN server on LinuxMint 17.1 using the following guide: [Click me](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04).

I followed up to the part where you start up OpenVPN with the following command: `service openvpn start`

That brought the following response:

`* Starting virtual private network daemon(s)...                                                                                                                           *   Autostarting VPN 'server'                                                                                                                                            foo-server random-folder #`

But when I check the service status it says that OpenVPN isn't running. Any ideas? This is my `/var/log/syslog`: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/giiUrtzj).

Thanks.

Comment: Two things, can you doublecheck that openvpn isn't running? ps -ef | grep -i vpn. I'm really not an openvpn expert but I seem to remember that this behavior is caused by mistakes in your server config file.

Comment: @SomeLinuxNerd I ran the command and got the following output: root      2972  2592  0 18:24 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto -i vpn

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Add the following lines 'log /var/log/openvpn.log' and 'verb 3' to a conf file, restart the openvpn and check the log file

Comment: @Iain I've linked a pastebin in there.

Comment: @ALex_hha What config file?

Comment: In the /etc/openvpn should be created configuration file, for e.g. server.conf

Comment: @ALex_hha Ok, do you want the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use `grep` to filter only the error related to openvpn, for example:

`tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep ovpn-server`

Anyway, from the syslog error you are getting:

`ovpn-server[16840]: Options error: --ifconfig-pool/--ifconfig-pool-persist requires --mode server`

It is very clear, you need to add the option `--mode server` too, in the config file for the `--ifconfig-pool` or `--ifconfig-pool-persist` to work.

So add a line with `mode server` in the server conf file and see.

Deatils config ref: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit of an OpenVPN noobie, so may I ask. Where do I put what?

Comment: Which guide have you followed?

Comment: It's the hyperlink labeled click me

Comment: Oops. I hyper linked the wrong thing. Sorry

Comment: Here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Pls post your /etc/openvpn/server.conf file

Comment: Here you go: pastebin.com/R5banmGN

Comment: It looks good. You have the entry, `mode server` at the end. It should work.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You can comment both the line with ifconfig and mode Server and restart and check syslog or openvpn.log

Comment: I got the following in openvpn.log: Options error: Parameter ca_file can only be specified in TLS-mode, i.e. where --tls-server or --tls-client is also specified.
Use --help for more information.

Comment: Comment the line with ca_file and restart. At best, chek the tutorial again and uncomment only those that are mentioned and See.

Comment: there isnt a line called ca_file.

Comment: @Njinx, add the line `tls-server` in server.conf and see. Also you have the option `verb 3` twice, can remove once.